# Appium Error: Could not find 'adb.exe' in PATH. (local environment is setup)

Tags: android, appium

I'm trying to create a session using the desktop appium, and I'm getting this error:

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb.exe' in PATH. Please set the ANDROID_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variables to the correct Android SDK root directory path.
```

Now I can use adb with no problem in my terminal, because I've setup adk in my pathway. And I got Java_home in my pathway too.

```
#all in my path
C:\Users\Sams PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools
C:\Users\Sams PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
C:\Users\Sams PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

So I don't quite understand why i'm getting this error. These are my desired capabilities:

```
{
  "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "app ": "C:\\Users\\Sams PC\\Desktop\\Android\\myapp-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk"
}
```

Here are the Appium logs:

```
[BaseDriver] Creating session with MJSONWP desired capabilities: {
[BaseDriver]   "app": "C:\\Users\\Sams PC\\Desktop\\Android\\myapp-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk",
[BaseDriver]   "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
[BaseDriver]   "platformName": "Android",
[BaseDriver]   "newCommandTimeout": 0,
[BaseDriver]   "connectHardwareKeyboard": true
[BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by Appium:
[BaseDriver]   connectHardwareKeyboard
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: e5a41011-c8e6-4d25-b1de-ea89de54a7b1
[BaseDriver] Using local app 'C:\Users\Sams PC\Desktop\Android\myapp-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk'
[UiAutomator2] Checking whether app is actually present
[ADB] The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set to the Android SDK root directory path. ANDROID_HOME is required for compatibility with SDK 23+. Checking along PATH for adb.
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1595009685037 (14:14:45 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time))
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not find 'adb.exe' in PATH. Please set the ANDROID_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variables to the correct Android SDK root directory path.
[MJSONWP]     at ADB.getBinaryFromPath (C:\Users\Sams PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\system-calls.js:140:11)
[MJSONWP] Destroying socket connection
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 443 ms - 288
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {}
[HTTP] No route found. Setting content type to 'text/plain'
[HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session 404 13 ms - 57
[HTTP]
```

As you can see, the problem clearly resides with it can't find adb.exe; however as you can see I have platform-tools within my path (this is why I can use adb in the terminal, so adb.exe is definitely in my path)

Comment: Can you share the appium desktop configuration?

Comment: The desired capabilities is the desktop configuration. I'm a bit confused by what you mean.

Comment: On the appium desktop server, there is an `Edit Configurations` section, there is an `Environment Variables` for setting `ANDROID_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME`, have you set it?

Comment: Where do you see Edit Configurations? I can't find that on the Appium desktop

Comment: @frianH I should mention, I can run adb on the terminal with no problems (because it is in my path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue. While I had set the PATH to Sdk and platform tools, you also have to **Create** System Variables for ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME. It's not enough to just set your path to them. So despite being able to run adb, the program needs pre-defined system variables.